# Flatten column values to comma seperated list

Tags: excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Given the following columns in a Excel compatible spreadsheet:

```
| CAT1 | CAT2 | CAT3 | 
|      |      | 1    | 
|      |    2 | 1    | 
| 1    |    3 | 2    |
```

I want to achieve:

```
| CAT1 | CAT2 | CAT3 | FLAT
|      |      | 1    | 1
|      |    2 | 1    | 2,1
| 1    |    3 | 2    | 1,3,2
```

with an Excel Function (or a combination of functions).

Is there something build in for that?

Comment: If you have Excel 2016, `TEXTJOIN` would do what you want.

Comment: `TEXTJOIN`, or use a series of helper columns, or write a VBA routine.

Comment: TEXTJOIN it is!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CAT1` in A1:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:C2)
```

in D2 and copied down to suit. Tested in LibreOffice Calc.